# Theming Civi Vs Drupal

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, evaluating-civicrm, theme

Since myself new to civi and drupal combination in certain case we need drupal as backend for few functionalities/workflow, and few functionalities works civi as backend. So my concerns is where would be the theme get placed ..whether we need to build two themes for civi and drupal differently. or theming will be common in one place? Please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7 at /admin/appearance you can specify what Drupal theme to use for front-facing civicrm pages, and separately which one to use for back-end civicrm interface.

Hope that helps. Not sure I quite understood your question but thought this might be what you need.

Comment: Missed it..This is the one which i am expecting. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different theme for different page of CiviCRM, please have a look at Page Theme module. its here https://www.drupal.org/project/page_theme