# Considerations when choosing a theme for Drupal 7 + CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, theme

I'm helping a non-profit with their website and we have chosen to go with Drupal 7 + CiviCRM, and are now looking at different themes

In the feature list for the Danland theme it says that it is "CiviCRM friendly", implying that other's might not be, so I'm wondering: **What we need to think about when choosing a theme for our Drupal 7 website?**

(More specifically: I have for example been looking at the Bootstrap theme which is the most popular, will this work well with CiviCRM?)

Grateful for help and with kind regards, Tord

Comment: I too am curious about this. The roadmap has 4.7.13 moving towards a more mobile friendly interface for CiviCRM. (see here: https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/responsive-design-improvements). If this is the case, what should the base theme be set at?)

Comment: Update: We ended up choosing Bootstrap and it works well, however there is a small problem in that the "labels" used by CiviCRM (for example on donation pages) are not visible because the font color is set to white. We solved this by adding CSS in a Bootstrap subtheme

Answer (score 5):

One consideration is to use different themes for the front office and the back office.

- The *front office* are the profile pages used to gather information from the constituents (or maybe you are using webforms in combination with webform_civicrm). These should be themed according to the official stylebook of your organization. They are part of the marketing strategy. It is often a limited set of screens, so almost any theme can be selected. But in these days responsive is a must, making bootstrap a good option.
- The *back office* are standard CiviCRM screens used by your internal staff for searching and processing the data. These are complex screens, that work best with a simple, readable theme that uses the complete screen. I use [adminimal](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) for this task.

More of this discussion can be found at [Theming Civi Vs Drupal](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/theming-civi-vs-drupal).